# How can I create an array without duplicates with this structure

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array structure:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '17',
    'name' => 'aba aba',
    'english_name' => 'ABA ABA',
    'group_id' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '23',
    'name' => 'bcb bcb',
    'english_name' => 'BCB BCB',
    'group_id' => '2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '17',
    'name' => 'aba aba',
    'english_name' => 'ABA ABA',
    'group_id' => '4',
  ),
);
```

I want to create another array with no duplicates but having in mind in which group_id are the duplicate ones. I'm looking for this structure:

```
array (
  17 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'ABA ABA',
    'groups' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
      1 => '4',
    ),
  ),
  23 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'BCB BCB',
    'groups' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
    ),
  ),
);
```

I tried with this code but it doesn't give me what I'm looking for, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**Code:**

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (!in_array($value['id'], $array[$value['id']] )) {
      $interested [$value['id']]['name'] = $value['english_name'];
      $interested [$value['id']]['groups'][]= $value['group_id'];
    } else if (in_array($value['id'], $array[$value['id']] )){
      $interested [$value['id']]['groups'][] = $value['group_id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your sample input data in a form that makes it easier for us to test this - use `var_export`.

Comment: Please show us what your current code gives you. You can also change the `else if (...)` to just `else`. If the first evaluates as false, then the second will always evaluate as true.

Comment: What's `$interested`?

Comment: Very similar: [PHP: Merge multi dimensional arrays, grouping by a certain key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25618777/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple loop and assign using the id as your pivot:

```
<?php
$data = 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '17',
    'name' => 'aba aba',
    'english_name' => 'ABA ABA',
    'group_id' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '23',
    'name' => 'bcb bcb',
    'english_name' => 'BCB BCB',
    'group_id' => '2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '17',
    'name' => 'aba aba',
    'english_name' => 'ABA ABA',
    'group_id' => '4',
  ),
);


foreach($data as $item) {
    $result[$item['id']]['name']     = $item['english_name'];
    $result[$item['id']]['groups'][] = $item['group_id'];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  17 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'ABA ABA',
    'groups' => 
    array (
      0 => '1',
      1 => '4',
    ),
  ),
  23 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'BCB BCB',
    'groups' => 
    array (
      0 => '2',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '17',
    'name' => 'aba aba',
    'english_name' => 'ABA ABA',
    'group_id' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '23',
    'name' => 'bcb bcb',
    'english_name' => 'BCB BCB',
    'group_id' => '2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '17',
    'name' => 'aba aba',
    'english_name' => 'ABA ABA',
    'group_id' => '4',
  ),
);
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) {
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();

    foreach($array as $val) {
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp_array;
}
$newdata = unique_multidim_array($data,'id');
```

The function taken from here. Details on : https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Any techniques with iterated `in_array()` calls will have poor performance.  The best way is to use temporary keys so that the output array also serves as a constantly updated lookup array.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear from your code what you are trying to do, but below is one way.

- Loop over your subarrays one by one.
- have a new array, say `$set`  which will be an associative array of keys and values where keys are the IDs and values are the `name` and `groups` attributes.
- If `$set` has the `ID` isset already, add to groups, else, create a new one and then add groups.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$set = [];

foreach($array as $val){
    $group_id = $val['group_id'];
    if(!isset($set[$val['id']])){
        $set[$val['id']] = [
            'name' => $val['english_name'],
            'groups' => []
        ];
    }
    
    $set[$val['id']]['groups'][] = $group_id;
}

print_r($set);
```

**Demo:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/af65effc35a0275bdf6908c77dc0cb701d36010e

Answer (score 0):

Functional way)

```php
function group( $groups, $item ) {
    $id = $item['id'];
    if ( !isset($groups[$id]) ) {
        $groups[$id] = array (
            'name' => $item['name'],
            'groups' => array(),
        );
    }
    array_push($groups[$id]['groups'], $item['group_id']);
    return $groups;
}

array_reduce($data, 'group', array());
```

[Please take a look at playground](https://tehplayground.com/EcaYL0W7Dh0HpuY6)

Also to make groups array unique PHP Collections could be used. For example, [Set data structure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ds-set.php).